# Automatic logging in Android

Tags: java, android, logging, logcat

I am a fan of debug logs (in debug builds), and I want to make some improvements to my custom logger class. Ideally, I would like to create a base method which logs the calling class name, method name, and parameter values.

For Example, say I have an Application "MyApplication" with Class "MainActivity", and I am calling method "foo" with parameter "bar". I would like to see something like this in the LogCat:

`D/MyApplication MainActivity foo("bar")`

Is there a way of getting this information without having to pass in all of these values manually? I've seen some articles referring to Java supported methods, such as java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles, but I haven't found any referring to Android supported methods. I expect parameters will have to be passed in, but automating the class name and method name would be excellent.

Answer (score 2):

Calling [`Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace()) can get you  the [`StackTraceElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) of the current thread. You can then call [`getClassName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html#getClassName()), [`getMethodName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html#getMethodName()) and [`getLineNumber()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html#getLineNumber()) to print out the class, method and line of code. It would look something like this in code.

```
StackTraceElement ste = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[0];
String msg = ste.getClassName() + "." + ste.getMethodName() + ":" + ste.getLineNumber();
```

Comment: Thanks @ChrisStillwell, I have seen answers such as this, and should have included it in my question. My question to this is what does the [3] represent? I have seen answers with [0] and [1], but I don't know what stack trace element is reliable.

Comment: The `[3]` was because I copy pasted this from a library I can use within my projects. Basically `getStackTrace()` returns an array of `StackTraceElement`s. The top of the array is the top most stacktrace (ie where this gets called). If you want the full trace looping through the array will get you the full hierarchy of calls. Identical to the stacktrace you get when an exception is thrown.

Comment: Basically, if I throw an exception at line 15 in `SomeMethod()` the stacktrace I see there will be identical to the one I can print out if I were to call `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` at line 15 in `SomeMethod()`.

Comment: Got it, so depending on how many methods you call before grabbing the stack trace, the index of the element will vary. Is there any way of grabbing the method parameters? I can pass in Object..., but the more automated, the better.